# Generate several random values where the sum equals a specified criteria (matlab)

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab)

I am looking to do the following:

Generate several random numbers between 10 and 50.

Have the sum of the random numbers equal 500.

What I have so far is:

```
sum = 500
n=5
b = [ ]
for i = 1:1:n-1,
a = randi([10,50])
b = [b a]
end
```

n=5 is in there as an example and can equal anything.

I am looking for the sum of b to equal 500 (That could be the difference between 'sum = 500' and sum of the values before the sum equals 500 -- making the last number not actually random, which is ok)

```
b =

23    10    43    30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this nice [random vectors generator with fixed sum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum) FEX file. I think this will answer your question.

Comment: This looks great. Just need to figure out how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: are the five variables contained in the following: randfixedsum(n,m,s,a,b) -- all that needs to be changed?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab for a more detailed answer...