# Matlab function for creating random number satisfying constraints

Tags: matlab, random

As an input I have two number x and y. `x>y`.
I want to create exactly `y` non-zero random number which their sum will be equal to `x`. I know `randi([min max])` function . Can you help me?

Comment: just recalled it might be a possible duplicate of [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got it right, you want something like this:

```
data = rand(1,y);
data = data * x / sum(data);
```

`data` will contain exactly `y` positive uniformly distributed numbers which sum equals to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the file [random vectors generator with fixed sum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum) in Matlab FEX. I believe this will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks I will check it just one thing all the y numbers should be non zero.

Answer (score 0):

Leonid's approach will certainly generate a set of random numbers that have the correct sum, but it won't select uniformly over the allowed space.  If this is important, an approach that will work is the following:

(with x = 1):

1. Generate Y-1 random numbers uniformly over [0,1].
2. Sort the Y-1 numbers from smallest to largest.  Call these {y1,...,y_{N-1}}
3. Take as the Y random numbers the set {y_1-0 ,y_2-y1,...,1-y_{N-1}} == {n_1,... n_Y}.

These n_i clearly sum to one. It is easy to prove uniformity by considering the probability for a given realization of the n_i.