# How to generate random numbers summing up to 100?

Tags: c++

I need to make four random generated numbers which sum have to be 100. Those numbers have to be in range from 1 to 100.

How can I do this?

Comment: Generate three random numbers and take the fourth to be 100 - sum.

Comment: How about generating 3 numbers and calculating last one as 100 - sum of those three?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, what if compiler generates 28, 74 and 99, sum of those numbers is over 100

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @Alen If the three numbers that you get sum up to 100 or more, throw them away, and try generating three new numbers. Do it in a loop until you get three numbers that sum up to less than 100.

Comment: but OP didn't say anything about negative numbers.  the range is not specified.  statistical properties are not specified.  the xkcd is appropriate :p

Comment: @Alen: Then just try again.

Comment: Are the numbers required to be integers?

Comment: Technically, they won't be random.

Comment: @thang I don't need negative numbers, only positive. I got lots of good solutions so I'll try them out.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8064629/1084416) on `matlab`. Do you want the results to be uniformly distributed?

Comment: @PeterWood No, I don't need it uniformly, I need it randomly with no rules, just sum of 4 numbers has to be 100. And I made it using the answer which I marked as ACCEPTED.

Comment: Well, `25, 25, 25, 25` might come up 10% of the time, is that what you want?

Comment: That's ok since range of numbers won't be 1-100 all the time, in some parts of application it will be 60-100 so accepted solution is perfect.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused.

Comment: hehe, Peter you don't have to be confused, it's long story, I just found that solution to be very good :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate four random numbers, for example in range 0..100, then rescale them to have 100 as sum:

`x_i' = 1 + x_i*96.0/sum`

**This solution does not provide uniform distribution of {x_i}.**

@PeterWood found better answer for this question [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab)

Comment: I don't understand this, can you explain please.

Comment: `double x1 = random(0, 100);
double x2 = random(0, 100);
double x3 = random(0, 100);
double x4 = random(0, 100);
double sum = x1+x2+x3+x4;
x1 *= 100.0/sum;
x2 *= 100.0/sum;
x3 *= 100.0/sum;
x4 *= 100.0/sum;`
Note: thats just pseudocode

Comment: correct, but if integers are required, you need to make sure the rounding happens properly. C++ uses floor for integer division, so in a bad case the integers x_i' would sum up to 97 only. Consider the numbers [24.9, 24.9, 24.9, 25.3], as floats they sum up to 100.0, but their integer sum would be 24+24+24+25=97.

Comment: x_i' = x_i * 100/(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)

Comment: yep, integer sucks. As a suggestion I may recomend to distribute remainder according to fractional part of a numbers

Comment: But, they're no longer random.

Comment: @Peter Wood
Distribution would not be uniform, but numbers would be random =)

Comment: No, they wouldn't. Given any 3 of the numbers you could predict the 4th. They're no longer random.

Comment: @PeterWood They **must** add up to 100 (according to the question). So of course you'll be able to predict the 4th. They should be random **subject to** this constraint.

Comment: @PeterWood there is just dependance (x1, x2, x3) -> x4

Comment: See answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8064629/1084416) on `matlab`.

Comment: @PeterWood yep, you are right here, but no one told about distributions. Random numbers with non-uniform distributions stay random. That was just the simpliest way to get random numbers which sum to particular value. But you provided a correct solution. I will append it.

Comment: I’m sorry to say that this solution is now wrong. These mummer sums 103. You need to replace 99 with 96.

Answer (score 3):

Generate first random number from range 1..97.

Then generate second random number from range 1..(98-first)

Then generate third random number from range 1..(99-(first+last))

Finally set the last number as 100 - (first+second+third)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will be an uneven probability distribution, if that's something OP cares about.

Comment: Besides that the OP asked for the range to start at 1, is there any rationale behind the limiting of the ranges instead of just taking three random numbers in the full range?

Comment: OP didn't requested specific probability distribution. The fact, that numbers have to sum to 100 is the main reason for inequal distribution, because one big number will always produce another three small ones.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Let's say, that these three numbers from the full range are 99, 87 and 76, what should be the last one? I wrote a solution, which will work with *any* pseudorandom generator. Imagine a broken one, which always returns a maximum value from the range. If you persistently tried to find three values from the whole range, your program would hang.

Comment: @Spook: Your method breaks as well, when I have a broken RNG that returns -1. Since you cannot reason about the possible outcomes of broken components, everyone assumes sane components.

Answer (score 3):

If integer in range [1,100] (with obviusly decay to [1,97]) is what you need:

```
double x1 = random(0, 1); 
double x2 = random(0, 1); 
double x3 = random(0, 1); 
double x4 = random(0, 1); 

double sum = x1+x2+x3+x4; 

int n1 = 1 + x1*96.0/sum; 
int n2 = 1 + x2*96.0/sum; 
int n3 = 1 + x3*96.0/sum; 

int n4 = 100 - n1 - n2 -n3;
```

Comment: Ok... I was writing... deleting

Comment: @Dukeling This is quite common on SO for few people to write similar answers in the same time, I see no reason go give downvote for that. Downvotes are for poor quality answers and this one perfectly answers the question.

Comment: Upss.. thank to both... I finded the way to salve the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Generate the first between 1 and 100-3, the second between 1 and 100-first-2, the third between 1and 100-(first+second)-1 and the fourth = 100-(first+second+third).

Comment: You don't want to generate for the fourth.

Comment: (not mine) Your method might produce `{1,1,1,2}`. The fourth number is definitely between 1 and (100-1-1-1).

Comment: Could you write: ...and the fourth = 100-(first+second+third).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the problem description says that each number has to be in the range of 1 to 100.  You could just vary the mod with each pass.  Something like:

```
int sum = 0;
std::vector<int> randomNums();
while (sum != 100) {
    const int randomNum = std::rand() % (99 - sum);
    sum += randomNum
    randomNums.push_back(randomNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Already answered above, but if anyone is looking for a working example to copy and try quickly:

int main()
{
std::vector<int> v1;

int randNum1 = rand()%(97) + 1;
int randNum2 = rand()%(98-randNum1) +1;
int randNum3 = rand()%(99 - (randNum1+randNum2)) +1;
int randNum4 = 100 -(randNum1+randNum2+randNum);

v1.push_back(randNum1);
v1.push_back(randNum2);
v1.push_back(randNum3);
v1.push_back(randNum4);

int sum = 0;
for(const auto &itr : v1)
{
    cout << itr <<endl;
    sum =sum+itr;
}
cout << "sum is : " << sum <<endl;

return 0;
```

}