# generate random numbers of which the sum is constant

Tags: random, numbers, sum

I am thinking if there is anyway to generate a set of random numbers of which the sum is always a constant. For example, 20 can be divided into 5 numbers ( 1, 2,3,4,10) I don't care what each of the 5 numbers is as long as their sum is equal to 20. Is there anyway to do so programmatically?

Comment: By "sum", do you mean "product"?  Even if you clarify that, the question is still very unclear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab/8068956#8068956

Comment: does the numbers Positives only or both negative numbers can be there?

Answer (score 16):

To get a uniform distribution, the trick is to think of your sum as a number line, and rather than generating random numbers for the segments, generate n-1 numbers as points along the line, and subtract to get the segments. Here's the function from [ojrandlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib):

```
static int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}
void ojr_array_with_sum(ojr_generator *g, int *a, int count, int sum) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count-1; ++i) { a[i] = ojr_rand(g, sum+1); }
    qsort(a, count-1, sizeof(int), compare);
    a[count-1] = sum;
    for (i = count-1; i > 0; --i) { a[i] -= a[i-1]; }
}
```

`ojr_rand(g, limit)` generates a uniform random integer from 0 to limit-1. This function then fills the array `a` with `count` random integers that add to `sum`. Shouldn't be too hard to adapt this to any other RNG.

Comment: +1. I think this is uniform in higher dimensions, but I'd need to prove it. None of the other answers so far are even close to uniform though. Note that the more general problem is a random sampling of N numbers that all lie in the interval [a,b] with a sum of X. And of course, generating random integers that sum to a given number is also an interesting and related problem.

Comment: Really is a beautiful solution. Taking the problem and turning it into something different and simpler which is equivalent and easily solved - genius.

Comment: How would you handle this if some of the constraints are not constant but are a function of the other random variables, say the limiter of a2 is a1/2? (i.e. a2 must be at most half of a1 and assuming there is no loop in these constraints)

Answer (score 2):

This method does the job, and also allows controlling the "difference degree" between the values (e.g. if you want the array values to be close one to another)

```
/**
     * Create array of positive integers which exactly sums to a given (integer) number.
     * @param {Number} number of items
     * @param {Number} sum  required sum
     * @param {Number} [d=100] difference degree between the values (0..100)
     */
    randomSumArray: function(len, sum, d) {
        var _sum = 0;
        var arr = [];
        var n, i;

        if (!d && d !== 0) {
            d = 100;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var from = (100 - d) * 1000,
                to = (100 + d) * 1000,
                n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from); //random integer between from..to

            _sum += n;
            arr.push(n);
        }

        var x = sum / _sum;

        _sum = 0; //count sum (again)
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i] = Math.round(arr[i] * x);
            _sum += arr[i];
        }

        var diff = sum - _sum;

        // Correct the array if its sum does not match required sum (usually by a small bit)
        if (diff) {
            x = diff / Math.abs(diff); //x will be 1 or -1
            var j = 0;
            while (diff && j < 1000) { //limit to a finite number of 'corrections'
                i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len + 1)); //random index in the array
                if (arr[i] + x >= 0) {
                    arr[i] += x;
                    diff -= x;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a Trick but still :)
i present this as a possible idea, not saying it is the best
(and mostly, you will need integers so it wont work anyway)

If the needed random numbers are not required integers:
then you can generate N random numbers between [0,1] and then normalize the array to your S :)

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
   arr[i] = rand;

cursum = 0;
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
   cursum+=arr[i];

norm = S / cursum;

for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    arr[i] *= norm;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers Generated are not necesserily Positive or whitin a range.
you can calculate the last number can be *S - SUM(A1..A[N-1])*

Selection of N-1 random numbers is obviously uniform,
and because the last number is anyway dependent on the rest of the numbers
(each set has only one option for the last number).

the uniformitty is not hindered.

```
Arr = new int[N];

int sum=0;
for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
{
    int x = getRandomInt();
    sum += x;
    Arr[i] = x;
}
Arr[N-1] = S - sum;
return Arr;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a library function to get the random numbers.

Now the random number you want is the generated random number mod the allowed sum.

Next you decrement the allowed sum by the number you just generated.

Let's say the first random number your library random number generator returns is 109.

So your first random number is 109 mod 20 = 9. Update your allowed total to 20 -9 = 11.

You keep going until your allowed sum is zero.

Note that I assume the number 5 you mentioned is just an example. If you want the number of random numbers to be exactly 5 you might have to modify this method.

Comment: Won't be uniform. This will create far too many distributions that are one big number and 4 small ones.

Comment: You are right - it won't be uniform. I didn't assume it would be required in this particular case, especially going by his example. In the general case, we would of course need uniform distribution.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to do this for array of values, that takes Sum and splits it into range of numbers at random.

```
    <html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(){
var array = [{
    order: '1-2480831',
    value: 2040
}, {
    order: 'BAESYS-2012-0001',
    value: 570
}, {
    order: 'BAESYS-2012-0002',
    value: 773
}, {
    order: '1-3840231',
    value: 299
}, {
    order: '1-3840298',
    value: 1609
}, {
    order: '1-3841519',
    value: 1940
}];

    var splitInto = 3;

    document.write("[");
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        document.write("{ Id : '"+array[i].order+"', Data : [");
    var result = RandGenerator(splitInto,array[i].value);
    var sum = 0;
            for(ii =0;ii<result.length; ii++){
                sum += result[ii];
            document.write(result[ii]+',');
            }
            document.write("]},");
    }
    document.write("]");
}

function RandGenerator(count, sum) {
    var a = [];
    for (iii = 0; iii < count-1; iii++) 
        { 
            a[iii] = getRandToValue(sum);
            sum -= a[iii];
        }
    a[count-1] = sum;
    return a;
}

function getRandToValue(maxRand)
{
    var random = Math.random();
    var computed = (maxRand)*random;
    return computed;
}

f();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

yes! try this algorithm

```
num1=rand()%20;  
num2=rand()%(20-num1);  
num3=rand()%(20-num1-num2);  
num4=rand()%(20-num1-num2-num3);  
num5=20-num4-num3-num2-num1;
```

so for sure the five numbers are random and they sum up to 20
[***you can do this using loop if you want***]

In general you can first randomly generate the number of numbers[n] that will sum up to the number in hand[K]

```
 n=rand()%k;--assuming the number of rand numbers you want are between 1 and k[sum]
    n1=rand()%k;
    n2=rand()%(k-n1)
    .
    .
    nn-1=rand()%(k-n1...-nn-2)
    nn=k-n1-n2...nn-1
```

I hope that will help you!

Comment: then there is a probability that one of the remaining 4 numbers will be one otherwise they will all be zero. If you want to have fair distribution you need to modify the algorithm. like use rand() mod 6 instead of rand() mod 20

Comment: I was trying to give a better solution. more better solution can be to  use algorithm like n1=(2+rand() mod 4) use this method for all the numbers except the last one which will be n5=20-n4-n3-n2-n1 .This will give numbers between 2 and 6