# Integer vector compositions of size K (Implementation in C++)

Tags: c++11, recursion, generator, combinatorics

A composition of an integer `v`  is a set of K integers such that their sum is `v` (and order matters). For instance the 3-sized compositions of 2 are:

```
2 0 0 
1 1 0 
1 0 1 
0 2 0 
0 1 1 
0 0 2
```

A simple C++ algorithm to obtains these compositions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461761/partition-and-composition-combinatorics-implementation-in-c):

```
void print(std::vector<int>& a) {
    std::ostream_iterator<int> i(std::cout, " ");
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), i);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void recurse(std::vector<int>& a, int pos, int remaining) {
    if (remaining == 0) { print(a); return; }
    if (pos == a.size()) { return; }
    for (int i = remaining; i >= 0; --i) {
        a[pos] = i;
        recurse(a, pos + 1, remaining - i);
     }
 }

int main() {
  int v = 2, k = 3;
  std::vector<int> a(k);
  recurse(a, 0, v);
  return 0;
}
```

But I need something a bit more complex:

I need to find the compositions of a integer *vector*. That is, given a vector v=(v1, v2, v3) I need to find all their individual compositions and then create all possible combinations. If  C is a matrix where I put a partition of v1 in the first row, a partition of v2 in the second row, and a partition of v3 in the third row, then the sum of row `f` in C gives `v[f]`

For instance, the vector (1,2) of size F=2, if we set K=2, can be decomposed in:

```
# all sets of K vectors such that their sum is (1,2)
C_1 = 1,0   C_2 = 1,0  C_3 = 1,0 C_4 =  0,1   C_5 = 0,1  C_6 = 0,1
      2,0         1,1        0,2        2,0         1,1        0,2
```

The goal is to apply some function to each possible C. How can I do it it C++? I don't mind using generators, recursive or iterative algorithms as long as it does de job (as fast as possible).

**Python**

The implementation in Python is quite nice using recursions, `yield`, and the `itertools` library

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Generator to yield all K-size compositions of integer n
def findCombiR(n,K):
    if K==1:
        yield [n]
        return

    for i in range(0,n+1):
        for result in findCombiR(n-i,K-1):
            yield [i] + result

# Generator to yield all K-size compositions of a F-length vector
def findCombiR_v(v,K):
    out = []
    for f in range(0, len(v)):
        out.append(findCombiR(v[f],K))

    return out

# Main
####################

v = [1,2]
F = len(v)
K = 2

# C stores F composition generators, one for each element in v.
C = findCombiR_v(v,K)
#"product" combines all possible outputs of the F generators
for c in itertools.product(*C): 
    c = np.reshape(c, (F,K))
    print(c, '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using recursivity:

We know how to generate all compositions of an integer (see code in the question). To generate matrices that represent all combinations of compositions of F integers, we just create all possible compositions of integer f, and each time we find a new composition we call the algorithm again to find all possible compositions of the integer f+1. Each time we find a composition in the last integer means we have completed a valid matrix C.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

void recursevec(arma::ivec v, arma::imat& C, int f, int pos, int remaining) {

    // If there is no remaining left, we completed a new composition for v[f]
    if (remaining == 0) { 

        // If elements in v left, get the combinations of v[f+1]
        if(f < (C.n_rows-1)){
            recursevec(v, C, f+1, 0, v[f+1]);
            return;
        } 
        // If last f, then we are done and we completed a new C
        else {
            std::cout << C << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    // If position pointer got out of the vector, 
    // then there is nothing to do
    if (pos == C.n_cols) { return; }

    // Else, continue allocating the remaining in all possible ways
    for (int i = remaining; i >= 0; --i) {
        C(f, pos) = i;
        recursevec(v, C, f, pos + 1, remaining - i);
    }
}

// Test vector compositions
int main() {
  arma::ivec v = {1,2};
  int F = v.size();
  int K = 2;
  arma::imat C(F,K);
  recursevec(v, C, 0, 0, v[0]);
  return 0;
}
```