# How to generate n random numbers between -100 to 100 in Excel which sum to zero?

Tags: excel

How to generate n random numbers between -100 to 100 in Excel which sum to zero? Like I want 
100
-50
-50
30
-30

basically random numbers that net to 0

Comment: Then they're not really random, are they? Is `n` pre-determined or also random? Are you looking for a formula or will VBA be OK?

Comment: Let us assume that n is 1000 and a formula will be great

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate N random numbers whose sum is a constant K - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782329/generate-n-random-numbers-whose-sum-is-a-constant-k-excel)

Comment: Can it be real numbers or only integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razvan's answer in the linked thread is excellent. Otherwise I'm not sure there is a literal answer, but for fun, try this...

Enter this formula in cells `A1:T50`:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(-100,100)
```

Enter this sum formula into cell `U51`:

```
=SUM(A1:T50)
```

Now make sure you can see cell `U51`. Save the file with the below macro (**and save all other work**) and call the macro, making sure you leave the sheet active (don't switch to other software):

```
Sub sumZero()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Do While Range("U51").Value <> 0
        Range("U51").Formula = "=SUM(A1:T50)"
    Loop
End Sub
```

My low power laptop takes between 5 seconds to 3 minutes to arrive at a set of randomly picked data that sums to zero.

Comment: I'll give a vote :), like the shorter code. Arguments about relative speed to follow...

Comment: Thanks :) ha ha yes... but sometimes the slowest trees bear the sweetest fruit, right?!...

Answer (score 1):

In cell **B1** enter the formula:

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

The run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, A As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")

    N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter number of samples", Type:=1)
    A.Clear
    Range("A1:A" & N - 1).Formula = "=RandBetween(-100, 100)"

    Do While Abs(Range("B1")) > 100
        Calculate
    Loop

    A.Value = A.Value
    Range("A" & N).Value = -Range("B1").Value
End Sub
```

The macro will ask you for the number of samples you need and then fill column **A** with N-1 samples.  The N<sup>th</sup> is calculated to drive the sum to zero.