# Excel Random Values with 2 Constraints

Tags: excel, math, random, excel-formula

I've been attempting to build a matrix in Excel with random values. However, these random values must follow two constraints, which are a limit in the column total and another in the line total.

Take this matrix as an example:

| Column A Total = 180 | Column B Total = 200 | Column C Total = 185 | Line Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Random 1 | Random 2 | Random 3 | 250 |
| Random 4 | Random 5 | Random 6 | 125 |
| Random 7 | Random 8 | Random 9 | 60 |

I can build a formula that allows the columns or the lines to have random values and add to the required total, however I can't arrive to a formula that combines both constraints.

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782329/generate-n-random-numbers-whose-sum-is-a-constant-k-excel) to define the formula that always adds to the required total.

To allow for a better explanation, see the example of the table above, where the random numbers are now replaced with actual numbers:

| **Column A Total = 180** | Column B Total = 200 | Column C Total = 185 | Line Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **200** | 20 | 30 | 250 |
| **10** | 80 | 35 | 125 |
| **5** | 30 | 25 | 60 |

As you can see, the total in the lines are correct, however the totals of the first column are incorrect and add up to more than what is allowed (215 > 180).

Note that the line values must add up to the total, however the columns must be less or equal, here are the conditions to clarify:

> Line Totals 
> Line1: SUM(Random1, Random2, Random3) = 250 
> Line2: SUM(Random4, Random5, Random6) = 125 
> Line3: SUM(Random7, Random8, Random9) = 60

> Column Totals 
> Column1: SUM(Random1, Random4, Random7) <= 180 
> Column2: SUM(Random2, Random5, Random8) <= 200 
> Column3: SUM(Random3, Random6, Random9) <= 185

The objective is to achieve it in Excel.
Is this possible using formulas only? Or is this an optimization problem for which solver is required?

Comment: I would set this up in the Solver. Check on here, I did answer one similar.

Comment: Can you post the link? I've been able to it in solver too, but it is not optimised, since I would need to run many solvers, each time I want to update the conditions.

Comment: It seems to be more generic than [Excel Sudoku generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-jazcAZH0s), but maybe you can use the same idea. The video implements a solution in VBA.

Comment: Solver is a cop out - see soln below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9g4Ets5USpU_94KtUwA?e=bV7gd0)/screenshots refer.

Caveat - your constraints are not entirely feasible - since row total must sum to column totals (by definition), one of the semi-inequalities (<=) must be set equal to the balance of the row totals ('line totals per your Q') over the other tow column totals.

Instead col 3 <=185 I use col 3 = 250+125+60 (row total sum) - col 1 (<=180) - col 2 (<=200); where the latter two (col 1, col2) are simply random numbers up to 180 and 200 resp.

I solve this in a similar way to the soln I provided a moment ago to the link you included in your Q see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74340904/13607672).

---

**Steps**

*Step 1*

[image: Step 1]

Key equations:

- Random numbers in table generated as follows: `=LET(x_,RANDARRAY(3,3,1,1000000,1),x_)`
- Random col totals (cols 1 & 2) as follows: =RANDBETWEEN(1,U) where U was upper boundary given for respective columns

*(solving on this basis will ensure equality with the column and row totals, simultaneously, cols 1 and 2 are guarenteed to be no greater than the values required per the Q; alternatively you could use randbetween(L,1e6) to ensure these col totals are no *smaller* than the corresponding cell values for respective cols.. - albeit not the Q)*

---

*Step 2*

- Finds % of cells in relation to overall values from step 1 using `E5#/SUM(E5#)`

[image: % in cells]

- Rebalance the column and row totals so that they have the same % spread as required/given row/col tots (noting the total value of original random numbes remains unchanged, hence random nature preserved) using `=E15:G15*E4:G4/SUM(E4:G4)/(E15:G15/SUM(E15:G15))` for column totals and `=H18*H5:H7/SUM(H5:H7)` for row totals (i.e. "lines")

[image: rebalance col and row totals from step 1 to conform to %s given]

[image: rebalancing row totals]

*Caveat - I'm not entirely sure this steps is even necessary, but it does help to explain the approach...*

---

*Step 3*

- Take cross-product of row and column probabilities / %s to determine joint probabilities for respective cells

[image: cross product]

---

*Step 4*

Apply cell % (step 3) to desired col/row totals  - Voila!

[image: calculating results]

Using =`D27#*G4` in this screenshot.

---

Comment: This answer is amazing, sorry for the delay, I was hoping to test it out in my much bigger file, this week but couldn't find the time. I will do so next week and give you feedback. Anyway, it seems precisely what I was looking for, thank you for your help!

Comment: np - hope larger file works out for you! Br, J