# Randomize matrix elements between two values while keeping row and column sums fixed (MATLAB)

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, probability

I have a bit of a technical issue, but I feel like it should be possible with MATLAB's powerful toolset.

What I have is a random n by n matrix of 0's and w's, say generated with

```
A=w*(rand(n,n)<p);
```

A typical value of w would be 3000, but that should not matter too much.

Now, this matrix has two important quantities, the vectors

```
c = sum(A,1); 
r = sum(A,2)';
```

These are two row vectors, the first denotes the sum of each column and the second the sum of each row.

What I want to do next is randomize each value of w, for example between 0.5 and 2. This I would do as

```
rand_M = (0.5-2).*rand(n,n) + 0.5
A_rand = rand_M.*A;
```

However, I don't want to just pick these random numbers: I want them to be such that for every column and row, the sums are still equal to the elements of c and r. So to clean up the notation a bit, say we define

```
A_rand_c = sum(A_rand,1);
A_rand_r = sum(A_rand,2)';
```

I want that for all `j = 1:n, A_rand_c(j) = c(j)` and `A_rand_r(j) = r(j)`.

What I'm looking for is a way to redraw the elements of rand_M in a sort of algorithmic fashion I suppose, so that these demands are finally satisfied.

Now of course, unless I have infinite amounts of time this might not really happen. I therefore accept these quantities to fall into a specific range: `A_rand_c(j)` has to be an element of `[(1-e)*c(j),(1+e)*c(j)]` and `A_rand_r(j)` of `[(1-e)*r(j),(1+e)*r(j)]`. This e I define beforehand, say like 0.001 or something.

Would anyone be able to help me in the process of finding a way to do this? I've tried an approach where I just randomly repick the numbers, but this really isn't getting me anywhere. It does not have to be crazy efficient either, I just need it to work in finite time for networks of size, say, n = 50.

To be clear, the final output is the matrix `A_rand` that satisfies these constraints.

Edit:
Alright, so after thinking a bit I suppose it might be doable with some while statement, that goes through every element of the matrix. The difficult part is that there are four possibilities: if you are in a specific element `A_rand(i,j)`, it could be that `A_rand_c(j)` and `A_rand_r(i)` are both too small, both too large, or opposite. The first two cases are good, because then you can just redraw the random number until it is smaller than the current value and improve the situation. But the other two cases are problematic, as you will improve one situation but not the other. I guess it would have to look at which criteria is less satisfied, so that it tries to fix the one that is worse. But this is not trivial I would say..

Comment: I see you are using `rand` rather than `randn`.Can the random values be of the normal distribution?

Comment: Uhm, well yes, in principle they could be. Uniform has a slight preference, but they are not going to be truly uniform anyhow, after all the changes made.

Comment: To randomize while keeping the sum of each row (or of each column) you could use a small variation of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab). Keeping the sum of rows _and_ columns seems to be much more difficult. I'm assuming you want a _uniform_ random distribution

Comment: If I understand you correctly, can't you just generate a random number between 0 and min(c,r), call it x0. Then generate a random number be between 0 and min(c,r)-x0, call it x1. Then generate a random number be between 0 and min(c,r)-x0-x1, call it x2. And so on and so forth.

Comment: @LuisMendo my intention is for it to be approximately uniform, yes. I understand that this is very hard to do, so it is ok if the numbers are a bit skewed, but in principle they should be uniform in the given range. The post you refer to does indeed make sense for a single column, but sadly that's not what I need :(

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 That will be a bit tricky to do I think, if I want to get the sums into the ranges I mention. This approach might get you somewhat close, but not close enough, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that rows/columns with a single non-zero entry in `A` automatically give you results for that same entry in `A_rand`. If `A(2,5) = w` and it is the only non-zero entry in its column, then `A_rand(2,5) = w` as well. What else could it be?

You can alternate between finding these single-entry rows/cols, and assigning random numbers to entries where the value doesn't matter.

Here's a skeleton for the process:

- `A_rand=zeros(size(A))` is the matrix you are going to fill
- `entries_left = A>0` is a binary matrix showing which entries in `A_rand` you still need to fill
- `col_totals=sum(A,1)` is the amount you still need to add in every column of `A_rand`
- `row_totals=sum(A,2)` is the amount you still need to add in every row of `A_rand`

```
while sum( entries_left(:) ) > 0

% STEP 1:
% function to fill entries in A_rand if entries_left has rows/cols with one nonzero entry
% you will need to keep looping over this function until nothing changes
% update() A_rand, entries_left, row_totals, col_totals every time you loop

% STEP 2:
% let (i,j) be the indeces of the next non-zero entry in entries_left
% assign a random number to A_rand(i,j) <= col_totals(j) and <= row_totals(i)
% update() A_rand, entries_left, row_totals, col_totals

end

update()
    A_rand(i,j) = random_value;
    entries_left(i,j) = 0;
    col_totals(j) = col_totals(j) - random_value;
    row_totals(i) = row_totals(i) - random_value;
end
```

Picking the range for `random_value` might be a little tricky. The best I can think of is to draw it from a relatively narrow distribution centered around `N*w*p` where `p` is the probability of an entry in `A` being nonzero (this would be the average value of row/column totals).

This doesn't scale well to large matrices as it will grow with `n^2` complexity. I tested it for a 200 by 200 matrix and it worked in about 20 seconds.