# 4 random numbers totaling 100

Tags: swift, arc4random

I want to generate 4 random numbers between 1 and 100 so that the total adds up to 100. How do I do that?

say result1)  20,10,40,30
result2 ) 33,33,33,1
etc. Thanks

Comment: See this answer.  It's not Swift, but it explains the algorithm. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18600737/1630618

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is:

```
Step 1: Generate four random numbers between 0 and 1
Step 2: Add these four numbers
Step 3: Divide each of the four numbers by the sum,
Step 4: Multiply by 100, and round to the nearest integer.
```

Comment: This is roughly the method used in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30156889/1187415 which is not unbiased.