# create a positive vector with desired one norm

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a vector in Matlab and the vector should be non negative and the one norm should be equal to something which i can input(say 1).

I tried searching online but couldn't come up with satisfactory suggestions.

Comment: what is non-negative, you mean non-negative in all dimensions? Do you want it to be random aside from those constraints

Comment: sorry! All the elements of the vector should be non negative

Comment: If you need a uniform distribution of the result see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8064629/2586922)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just generate a random vector using `rand` and then use `norm` to compute the norm of the vector by which you would divide all elements. You could then multiply the result by your input value to scale it to the desired length.

If  you want the L1 norm, you would use the following.

```
% This will use the L1 norm
vec = rand(1, 10);
vec = vec * scale ./ norm(vec, 1);
```

This could be generalized to the `p` norm with the following:

```
vec = rand(1, 10);
vec = vec * scale ./ norm(vec, p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate elements between `0` and `1` (i.e. non-negative by definition) randomly:

```
v = rand(n,1)
```

Then scale it by diving by it's one norm (i.e. it now has a one norm of `1`) and multiplying by your desired one norm, `k`:

```
V = k*v/norm(v,1)
```