# how to create array of random normalize number?

Tags: arrays, matlab

i want to create a matrix that each row of the matrix have 7 real random number in [0,1]  and the sum of number in each rows  should be equal to 1.
this matrix have 100 rows and 7 columns. how can i do it?
 at first ,i create an array with 1 row and 7 columns. then write the code as bellow. i try normal the number in the rows but sum of each row became more than 1.how can i fix it? thank for taking your time.

```
a = rand(1,7);
for i=1:7
a(i) = a(i)/sum(a);
end
sum(a)
```

Comment: If you additionally want each row to be _uniformly distributed_ (you don't specify) you need an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8064629/2586922). Generating statistically independent samples and dividing by the obtained sum won't work

Comment: @LuisMendo I was just about to write the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `100` by `7`, you can use `bsxfun`:

```
a = rand(100,7);
a = bsxfun(@rdivide,a.',sum(a.')).';
```

Here the sum of each row `= 1`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by using a for-loop, you're changing the sum of the vector every loop iteration. You should take advantage of MATLAB's ability to act on whole matrices at once:

```
a = rand(1,7);
a = a./sum(a);
```