# Generate random numbers according probability distribution functions

Tags: matlab, random, probability

How to generate **different** random numbers according to probability distribution functions, using Matlab, where the generated numbers must be **different, between 0 and 1 and the sum of these numbers is  equal to 1**

Comment: if their sum is 1 you dont need to generate 2 numbers.

Comment: Once you have a distribution of numbers between 0 and 1, you can impose your sum condition by dividing each number by the sum of them all.

Comment: If the numbers are all different, they aren't as random any more

Comment: And if you impose the condition that the sum is `1`, their distriution functions may be altered (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068956/2586922))

Comment: @MadPhysicist What do you mean by "If the numbers are all different, they aren't as random any more"?

Comment: Your sequence has a restriction on it preventing it from containing some numbers. That makes it less random.

Comment: @MadPhysicist which ones? Below I posted solution via Dirichlet distribution, with \vec{alpha} = 1 all marginal distributions will be U(0,1).

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), and below is the code to sample from it. Simplest case is when all parameters are equal to 1

----------------- taken from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/65818.html?) ---------------------

The Dirichlet is a vector of unit-scale gamma random variables, normalized by 
their sum. So, with no error checking, this will get you that:

```
a = [1.0 1.0 1.0];
n = 10000;
r = drchrnd(a,n)

function r = drchrnd(a,n)
p = length(a);
r = gamrnd(repmat(a,n,1),1,n,p);
r = r ./ repmat(sum(r,2),1,p);
```