# Normalize matrix to values in [0,1] by dividing by row-wise sum

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a matrix (`population`, with 8 columns and 100 rows) of positive and negative numbers.

I want to create a matrix where each row has 8 real numbers which satisfy:

- All numbers are in the range [0,1]
- The sum of numbers in each row should be equal to 1

I wrote the code below. I tried to normalize the number in the rows but it doesn't work because the result contains negative numbers.

```
population(:,1:8) = bsxfun(@rdivide,population(:,1:8).',sum(population(:,1:8).')).';
```

How can I fix this?

---

For example, the input `[1 -2 3]` should give the output `[0.375 0 0.625]`

Comment: If you want a uniform distribution (restricted to sum 1), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8064629/2586922)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to subtract the row-wise minimum (regardless whether it's negative) and divide by the row-wise sum. You can use the `dim` argument of `min` and `sum` to specify the value should be taken row-wise...

```
% Get positive values by subtractive the row-wise minimum
pos = bsxfun(@minus, data, min(data, [], 2));
% Normalise by dividing by the row-wise sum
normalized = bsxfun(@rdivide, pos, sum(pos,2));
```

For example:

```
data = [5     6     0
        6     3     2
       -1    -2     6];
pos = bsxfun(@minus, data, min(data, [], 2))
>> pos = 
      [5    6    0
       4    1    0
       1    0    8]
normalized = bsxfun(@rdivide, pos, sum(pos,2)) 
>> normalized = 
     [0.4545    0.5455         0
      0.8000    0.2000         0
      0.1111         0    0.8889]
```

---

Note: from MATLAB 2016b, the *new* implicit expansion methods mean you don't need `bsxfun`, and can simply do

```
pos = data - min(data, [], 2);
normalized = pos ./ sum(pos, 2);
```

Comment: @Adiel element-wise `./` in fact, but thanks for spotting the typo!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it likes the following:

```
col_size = size(matrix,2);
matrix = matrix - repmat(min(matrix.').', 1, col_size); % minus minimum
normal_matrix = matrix./repmat(sum(matrix, 2), 1, col_size);
```

using `sum(matrix, 2)` to get sum of rows. Then apply `repmat` to repeat this columnar matrix to get a matrix with size of the original matrix. Then divide the original matrix with the repeated columnar matrix.

Comment: @hsi I don't think so. Be more precise.

Comment: sorry that comment was for lbezito ,not for you.

Comment: i have the matrix with negative number. i want to normalize that matrix.result should have positive number. i think your suggest create Repetitious culumn of data? is not?

Comment: For Matlab 2016b and up, you can use arithmetic expand: `matrix./sum(matrix,2)`

Comment: @hsi you have to give an explicit example for input and desired output

Comment: i have a matrix . it is not normalize. some of this data is negative. it is the input of code. each row of this matrix should have positive normalize number in [0,1]. and the sum of number in each row should be equal to 1.it is the out put.

Comment: This is not an example. I don't know what you mean by normalizing negative and positive values... Look at @wolfie's comment

Comment: input have negative numbers .is your suggest code result in positive numbers? i want to have positive number in result.

Comment: example for one row of matrix =>input: 1  -2   3 , output : 0.375  0  0.625

Comment: what would be the result of [-3 5] and [0 0 0] ?

Comment: i use this code instead of the code in question but it have sum not equal to 1.my code is:population = zeros(100,8);
population = rand(100,8);
for ii=1:size(population,1)
    population(ii,:) = (population(ii,:) - min(population(ii,:))) / ( max(population(ii,:)) - min(population(ii,:)))/(sum(population(ii,:)));
end

Comment: @hsi again. my code is different. You've written answer of Ibezito.