# Uniformly divide `n` doubles with a total sum `s`, where each double is below 1 (with proper performance)

Tags: java, performance, random, range, uniform-distribution

I'm currently working on [this (code-golf) challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/165043/52210), and I'm having a hard time of combining the four requirements given an integer-amount `n`, and total decimal-sum `s` (given the ranges we're supposed to support: `1 <= n <= 10` and `0 <= s <= n`):

1. The `n` items should all be random, and uniformly divided
2. The total sum of all items must be equal to `s`
3. None of the items may be above 1.0
4. The code must run within 1 second for every `n <= 10`, regardless of `s`

Based on [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064754/1682559) I know how to uniformly divide items in a given range. For example, with `n=5, s=4.5`, I could create a list of `n-1 = 4` items in the range `[0, 1.5]`, with an additional leading `0` and trailing `1.5`. Then I can calculate all the differences (so the total sum of all differences will be equal to `s=4.5`). Here a possible implementation of that:

```
int n=5; double s=4.5;

double[] randomValues = new double[n+1];
randomValues[n] = s;
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
  randomValues[i] = Math.random()*s;
java.util.Arrays.sort(randomValues);
System.out.println("Random values:\n"+java.util.Arrays.toString(randomValues)+"\n");

double[] result = new double[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  result[i] = Math.abs(randomValues[i]-randomValues[i+1]);
System.out.println("Result values:\n"+java.util.Arrays.toString(result)+"\n");

double resultSum = java.util.Arrays.stream(result).sum();
System.out.println("Sum: "+resultSum);
System.out.println("Is the result sum correct? "+(s==resultSum?"yes":"no"));
```

Example output:

```
Random values:
[0.0, 1.3019797415889383, 1.9575834386978177, 2.0417721898726313, 4.109698885802333, 4.5]

Result values:
[1.3019797415889383, 0.6556036971088794, 0.08418875117481361, 2.0679266959297014, 0.39030111419766733]

Sum: 4.5
Is the result sum correct? yes
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jVI9b8IwEN3zK06ekkZYRSoLaYQ6dmApUheawQS3mCY28l2oEOK300sCKA0taoZE8fvwvWev1VYN1svPY14oRJgqY/cBwKZaFCYHJEX82TqzhJKhcEbe2I95BiraH4EfYwlsOkpg6ViiAdMHOUqCoMbaJSZ7ZZeufFVFpRFSsPrrjNl4mCUNucuZ24xp2ALvzof1LiYdJmAeLb/iOGqgnsrUqqmilWyXw@ju5LHmlLIiU8gn79UOJTpPYVcctcTZDkmX0lUkN5yUChuKl4YG24Y3frMivrIj1xbz0zIWTI6uytBYFdSrIetnvf8layPspFQLDHsFDH7@c7u3grWT/C9Yw71Eqi07sU6zzaqSZ7sum7xW5dlCYsUn8/dUbDIGEV8cb1CfEWh13hzYF3Lnvc5pwgYhpunFZCJ2GsVYWCeiKOGbewgOx28)

This above complies to three of the four requirements above (1, 2, and 4). However, not to 3.

---

I could wrap a loop around it, which continues as long as one of the items in the `result`-array is still larger than 1:

```
for(boolean flag=true; flag; ){
  ... // Same code as above

  flag=false;
  for(double d:result)
    if(d>1)
      flag=true;
}
```

This still works relatively fast for most `n` and `s`:
[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##lZRNk6IwEIbv/oouTrBoAJGaRdadmuMe5rIztZfdOUQJGjfCFAlOWVP@drfDh6CitfYBSNJ5uvttkjXd0tE6/ntYCColPFOefg4A3ou54AuQiip8bTMewwaXzBeV83T5@w2opd0AEtMbgku@WhGcmePA64qBRH/BgCu2AS6Big@6k3qH48FMv2vMWGPcXsyTEOV@3J2zluA645LgNom4/YhbBM/tQ1TmtSSN2LKcLhlkSU3ictrxPZKaiW5ZQX9Z/cSgLmsc1Ah/CN41ZfoQ6Oz4iPCJ7/uEkBozGcL4Hgw6O5Myk6CjTnBF4D5C0ArcIIIhTO6RA52doCSEA@1VJRGShwvGNYL2bbIIH4ITShj@PyUMj5QwPKO0VvFuUVrr8Fqrydhz/57T4Nc998pfeT/AR/fsJiZPFaRDiDM82Hgorc@DxlVDPM45k4VQCEjZRzObvkVl16rWZbk5zzLBaAqJoMuZygsWlZ8R1HdBl0fTONv8oqJg8oxqezUXTrwwHDrKZknH0znzmRcB/5biw7atQaPDyU6udz5TtSLVtGl9OXLWeL@RQnFBnvIclSIyy5XZ3W5Fg4uYbm/MUqNONDqX5lkio9Mx1trBa9kSKiTrFll3JJ5W@DYcT8z4u9eOoaN7ObmvwC87iX8DyQpF3vFyViI1jZ9VO7dlGtM/qWFf6KCy6i4367i2gW5Wp@N1YtXyS7HBqi/FVDmjmwZBZIHaR1ezQsgUDPtIvOH6Q4JaNcEBubDI8pwt1CMCTDmbHSGPxo5JY2qkmWE1WvcQb8Qa3W3GdZoVHXRn9od/) (prints are removed/moved to not overflow the console)

However, the four `//`-disabled test cases at the end, with averages of the expected random values nearing the `1`, take way too long (and even time out after 60 seconds on TIO).

So this is where my question is mostly about. **How to uniformly divide the values like I did, AND keep in mind the range of `[0, 1]` for each values, AND have a good performance?** In the linked code-golf challenge at the top I see some working examples in other programming languages, like Python or JavaScript, but porting longer code-golfed challenges from one programming languages to another usually isn't very straight-forward..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution based on the JavaScript answers that were already given. If `s*s>n` I change `s` to `n-s` and set a flag to use `1-diff` instead of `diff` in the result-array.

So in total it becomes:

```
boolean inversedFlag = 2*s>n;
double S = s;
if(inversedFlag)
  S = n-S;

double[] result = new double[n];

for(boolean flag=true; flag; ){
  double[] randomValues = new double[n+1];
  randomValues[n] = S;
  for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    randomValues[i] = Math.random()*S;
  java.util.Arrays.sort(randomValues);

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    double diff = Math.abs(randomValues[i]-randomValues[i+1]);
    result[i] = inversedFlag ? 1-diff : diff;
  }

  flag=false;
  for(double d:result)
    flag |= d>1;
}

System.out.println("Result values:\n"+java.util.Arrays.toString(result)+"\n");

double resultSum = java.util.Arrays.stream(result).sum();
System.out.println("Sum: "+resultSum );
System.out.println("Is the result sum correct? "+(s==resultSum?"yes":"no"));

System.out.println();
System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
System.out.println();
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lZXPb5swFMfv@SueOEGTQAhFHWFp1cukHXZZpl22HtxgWnfEVNikqrr@7dkztoGkJFp8gMT@vs/7ZZsnsiXTp@zPbl0QIeAbYfxtBPBc3xdsDUISia9tyTLY4JK7khXjD7/ugHhKBpC74QRm/icvhYMRBPDjkYJAfUGBSboBJoAUL@RVKIsghKV6G8xcYWaDmNuiaOzRuqIdYRbMG8LMBjIbRpwihLMhhB5hR1KILa3IA4UyNyQmFj1tS7IT/bTi4bSGibFJax4bRDSB8FhlhhAoDiJERH4URb7vG8zlBObnYFAcXDaRxL3qxEcKPESIuwJbRDyBy3PKgeIgbghJL4jEv/rAOEZQWhtFchXvUZLk/ylJ0lKS5IDSDc07RelGj9eNrufROachMj0P97ZyOHAcjhHC9jhoxvsIH/3zn7uMS@ATyEq8HPBge287Bbwvy4ISDoxjyoJmXwrygJT5hbjmaROMMVjhrNAzTME6uTfSsSkFn67SUc8M75qKirqQao2@2Fl@p0k627JybRg58payqmna/EzBXFR9HuFZuflJipqKA@o4NFzYU6E7FK7skvKnisGWYQrsM8fHeGyTOLBkyvIbkY@@nna9i5bzhJevX0tW@LdVhU3wRVlJt2/umVr0fc56Pt9ap6bIGctz65DcC/cglun@f0zXS7u4mzrriPe6eQPhtAEvGr61eG9jUzXPSSFov0I2ooXmdvVRcvi7hOw61HoDWr0K3JV@WUv/GT8zsuCu8133ftsEvPjNnfGHoslSf5Vc42fsoMzrbQ8TiF5e1RtM72PlZUXJxiJ8UWOj0qNRIWQBzrgjntB@FSAfrXdAMKzLqqJreYMEVyyXLeXGeaXCWTi8dDzb@AHiCV/Ts4dznOalO9Wa990/)

Now I just have to golf it again, but that's irrelevant for this Stackoverflow question. :)