# Add noise to vector that sums up to 0

Tags: matlab, random

I have a vector that is defined by `a=[1000 1000 1000 1000 1000];`. I am asked to add uniform noise in the interval [-9,9], but the still save the sum of all elements at 5000. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add uniform random noise with `rand`. From the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html):

> In general, you can generate N random numbers in the interval (a,b) with the formula r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1).

```
vec = [1000 1000 ... 1000];
noise = -9 + 18 * rand(size(vec));
```

Then you need to center the noise around 0:

```
noise = noise - mean(noise);
```

Finally, you add it to the initial vector:

```
vec = vec + noise;
```

For example:

```
>> vec = [1000 1000 1000 1000 1000];
>> noise = -8 + 18 * rand(size(vec));       
>> vec_noise = vec + noise - mean(noise)

vec_noise =

   1.0e+03 *

    1.0002    0.9968    1.0021    0.9988    1.0020

>> sum(vec_noise)

ans =

        5000
```

Comment: Your Matlab quote left off "a" or substituded "vec" for "a". s/b: `a + (b-a).*rand(N,1)`

Comment: There is a chance that, after centering the noise around 0, the values are no longer in the selected interval. I think this needs a rejection scheme.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is only an approximation for large number of samples.

Answer (score 1):

I know its not an elegant way, but you can draw noise for every vector element in a loop, check the sum of previous noise and possible max and min of remaining noises. If your current noise + sum of previous noise would exceed possible remaining range, draw again (in new range). The last element's noise must be set to get noise sum equal to zero.

Comment: _The last element's noise must be set to get noise sum equal to zero._ But that spoils the "uniform noise" requirement: not all (vectored-valued) samples will have the same probability; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8064629/2586922)