# Create exchanges with bounded random parameters and fixed sum to be used in Montecarlo

Tags: brightway

I have to run a montecarlo where, for some products, certain exchanges are relate to each other in the sense that my process can take as input any of the products in different (bounded) proportions but with fixed sum.

Example:

my product `a` takes as inputs a total of `10 kg` of `x`,`y`, and `z` alltogheter and `x` has a uniform distribution that goes from `0` to `4` kg, `y` from `1` to `6` and `z` from `3` to `8` with their sum that must be equal to `10`. So, every iteration I would need to get a random number for my three exchanges within their bounds making sure that their sum is always 10.

I have seen that in [stats_array](http://stats-arrays.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#params-arrays)  it is possible to set the bounds of the distributions and thus create values in a specified interval but this would not ensure that the sum of my random vector equals the fixed sum of 10.

Wondering if there is already a (relatively) straightforward way to implemented this in bw2

Otherwise the only way I see this feasible is to create all the uncertainity parameters with  [ParameterVectorLCA](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2calc.html?highlight=parametervectorlca#vector-monte-carlo-lca), tweak the value in the array for those products that must meet the aforementioned requirements (e.g with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068956/4929813) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964954/4929813)) and then use this array with modified parameters to re-run my MC .

Answer (score 0):

We are working on this in https://github.com/PascalLesage/brightway2-presamples, but it isn't ready yet. I don't know of any way to do this currently without hacking something together by subclassing the `MonteCarloLCA`.